# How do I define a Cloud Datastore "kind"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-datastore

I've been going over the docs for Google Cloud Datastore. I have connected to it via a Google Apps Script and want to experiment with using it instead of GAS's built in ScriptDB which has many problems.

I can't figure out how to define a "kind" with the JSON API. It looks like I can write objects, but it is required that each object be a "kind" of a certain type. I've seen how to define them in the Google App Engine using Python, but I don't think that applies here.

Answer (score 5):

As a (realtively) schemaless transactional database solution, the Cloud Datastore does not need to be told about a kind before you write an Entity of that kind. Simply construct a Entity with the desired kind in its Key's path.

See the [Kinds and Identifiers](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Kinds_and_Identifiers) documentation for examples.